# drawer menu not doing anything on Click event

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Iam Implementing navigation drawer in my application but its menu not working on click. I dont know whats wrong but on click event is not doing anything or toasting a message.Click anything from drawer menu dont do anything.Firstly other button were also not working but adding them in a seprate layout solved the issue.but drawer menu are still not working

Here is my xml :

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here in java Iam using it :

```
public class AuthorMainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_author_navigation);

        viewDeclaration();
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void viewDeclaration() {
        newSurveyBtn = findViewById(R.id.new_surveys_button);
        surveyWithRef = findViewById(R.id.get_survey_button);
        surveyResult = findViewById(R.id.analyze_survey);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_share:
                System.out.println("ss" + "coming");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_survey_count:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Surveys", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_logout:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you don't have to wrap the layout you wish to include with the LinearLayout tags. If that layout is Linear already that information will be brought in to the new layout anyway.

Comment: if I dont wrap that layout with linear then button in that layout also wont work
Wrapping them make them work but drawer menu is stiil not working

Comment: are you binding the views properly? What's in that layout?

Comment: that view is working fine the issue is in navigation menu thats not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this is in the XML file bring navigation view below the include tag and it will work

Change this

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To this

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />
    </LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

Comment: this saved my day after weeks of struggle to the point I was giving up on java for andriod. Kotlin's knocking at my door real hard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize **actionBarDrawerToggle**. You have to do it.

Comment: that dosen't matter

Comment: @Umair right now you're setting a null listener, how doesn't this affect things?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using AndroidX try to use the methods related to it.

Add the host fragment when you want to implement the fragments in that particular activity:

xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

</LinearLayout>

  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

Now use the navigation graph where you need to implement the fragments you are about to use in the activity :

navigation_graph.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/profile">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:name="com.example.jetpacknavigationexample.Fragments.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="@string/profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/features"
    android:name="com.example.jetpacknavigationexample.Fragments.FeaturesFragment"
    android:label="@string/features"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_features" />
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/signout"
    android:name="com.example.jetpacknavigationexample.Fragments.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="@string/signout"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_signout" />
  </navigation>
```

In your java class add the implement the Navigation component code :

```
public class AuthorMainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

//Add this
 NavController mNavController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_author_navigation);

   //add this
    mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.host_fragment);







 NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavController, drawerLayout);

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,mNavController);

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    viewDeclaration();
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void viewDeclaration() {
    newSurveyBtn = findViewById(R.id.new_surveys_button);
    surveyWithRef = findViewById(R.id.get_survey_button);
    surveyResult = findViewById(R.id.analyze_survey);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_share:
            System.out.println("ss" + "coming");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_survey_count:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Surveys", 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_logout:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logout", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

You can test your app now. let me know after you implement this.